# QGIS 3.4.3 Refactor fields changes symbols in fields (cp1250)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, encoding

I've been using QGIS Refactor fields to change type, re-order and rename a substantial ammount of columns (statistical data). Most of them hold purely numerical values and are as such not material to whatever decoding/encoding happens between various codepages, except for one. This column holds names (place names) which contain characters č, š and ž. Original data I procured is encoded in utf-8. For various practical reasons I exported them as cp1250 (default for all the computers involved) which produced exactly the same file with properly displayed symbols (čšž).
When I applied Refactor fields everything was copied to a new file but č symbol was exchanged for c, while š and ž remained as they were.

I don't see any way to specifiy encoding in Refactor fields and since this is based on Python (which I know defaults to utf-8 in 3.x) means that I have encountered this kind of problem before. In Python that could be corrected by specifiying a codpage (in most cases).

What else could be the source of this issue and, in particular, can it be avoided using the command line version of the Refactor fields tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is easily solvable by using the ... button next to the field for output. It just pays to be consistent.

[image: Change encoding]